# Saving image\file

Tags: android, external, internal, saving-data

The issue is to save image to the storage
This code worked fine, but not with Android 6 and N

What do I need to fix here?
Or as an option - using another example for saving to internal\external files

```
public void saveImage(Bitmap icon) {

        File ff;        
        File file = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Folder Name");

        ff = new File(file.getAbsolutePath() + file.separator + imageName + ".jpg");
        if(ff.exists()){

            Log.i("sharing", "File exist SD");
        } else{
        try {
            File f = null;
            if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {

                if (!file.exists()) {
                    file.mkdirs();
                }
                Log.i("sharing", "File exist Internal");
                f = new File(file.getAbsolutePath() + file.separator + imageName + ".jpg");
            }
            FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(f);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 10, ostream);
            ostream.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }

    }
```

And permissions from Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Thanx

Comment: Have you asked for permissions with the new Permission system?

Comment: Did you add permission ?

Comment: You might consider editing your question and explaining, in detail, what "This code worked fine, but not with Android 6 and N" means. What are your specific symptoms? For example, are you crashing? Have you examined LogCat?

Comment: Guys, I've already updated my question with permissions. Take a look, please. Do I need smth to add?

Comment: @CommonsWare, no crash, logcat is ok, but file doesn't save in the storage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added permissions for android sdk > 22

This code works perfectly

```
 if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(HomeActivity.this,
                            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {                                              
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(HomeActivity.this,
                                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},23
                                    );

                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put the uses-permission-sdk-23 tag and   set the permission you want.

Then
You should check whether the permission is granted or not by calling the checkSelfPermission and pass the permission name as argument

If the permission is not granted you should gain the permissions by calling the requestPermissions method  and pass the permissions names as string array and the request code

After that
A dialog will be shown to user and ask them if the permission is granted or not

Then a interface onRequestPermissionResult will be called and you should implement this into your activity class

After that
You can gain access to the requested permissions if the user granted it